# Formula for $\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^q $

Tags: sequences-and-series

I found that
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^q =\frac{n^{q+1}}{q+1}+\frac{n^q}{2}+\frac {1}{2} \binom{q}{1} B_2 n^{q-1} +\frac {1}{4} \binom {q}{3} B_4 n^{q-3} +\frac{1}{6} \binom {q}{5} B_6 n^{q-5}+\dots$$

But I couldn't prove this and I don't know how can I start this.

I really need your help.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula

Comment: Oh Thak you so much!